# Compare values in two different workbooks sheets and paste value of 1st workbook into 2nd workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Want to Compare the value incrementally from sheet1 of workbook1 with value of sheet1 of workbook2 and copy paste data of sheet 1 to sheet 2 if values match, WB1S1 contains three columns two value to compare and thirs to copy, WB2S1 contains two columns both to compare with WB1S1 first two columns if value match copy WB1S1 third column values to WB2S1, , the value can be any way, e.g  A1:B1 of WB1S1 matches A2:B2 of WB2S1 then, C1 of WB1S1 to be copied to C2 of WB2S1

Here is the code

```
Sub Compare()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim myTemp As Workbook, myMain As Workbook
Dim temppath As String, mainfile As String
Dim wsTempwsMain As Worksheet, wsMain As Worksheet

temppath = "workbook1.xlsx"
mainfile = "workbook2.xlsx"

Set myTemp = Workbooks.Open(filename:=temppath)
Set wsTemp = myTemp.Sheets("Sheet1")

Set myMain = Workbooks.Open(filename:=mainfile)
Set wsMain = myMain.Sheets("Sheet1")

wsTemp.Activate
wsMain.Activate

Dim TemplastRow As Long, MainlastRow As Long
Dim MainLastColumn As Long


TemplastRow = wsTemp.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row

MainlastRow = wsMain.Range("B4").End(xlDown).Row

With wsMain.UsedRange
    MainLastColumn = .Columns(.Columns.Count).Column
End With
 
For i = 2 To TemplastRow
    For j = 4 To MainlastRow
            
        If myTemp.wsTemp.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 2)).Value = myMain.wsMain.Range(Cells(j, 2), Cells(j, 2)).Value And myTemp.wsTemp.Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)).Value = myMain.wsMain.Range(Cells(j, 3), Cells(j, 3)).Value Then
            myTemp.wsTemp.Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, 8)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            myMain.wsMain.Range(Cells(j, MainLastColumn), Cells(j, MainLastColumn)).Select
            wsMain.Paste
        End If
    Next j
Next i

 myWb.Save
myWb.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that `Dim temppath, mainfile As String` only declares `mainfile` as `String` but `temppath` as `Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim temppath As String, mainfile As String` otherwise they are `Variant` by default. Same for your other variable declarations.

Comment: Best to avoid Activate and Select.  Just make the two cells equal to avoid copy and paste.

Comment: Can you not do this with a `VLookUp`?

Comment: @DarrellH can you elaborate a bit more, will it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to start two rows behind the first dataset.  If you loop through twice you are going to multiply the number of checks times the number of rows in the second dataset.  If this is the case, you start with `i` and just use `i+2`(instead of `j`) for the row in the second dataset.  To avoid copy and paste, you would replace the copy and paste lines by making the cells equal within the loop, such as:

`wsMain.Range(Cells(i+2, MainLastColumn), Cells(i+2, MainLastColumn)) = wsTemp.Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, 8))`